# Unrecognized selector - using indexpath.row to send a string to view2

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

Im having trouble passing a string to a second view.  I am trying to grab the indexpath.row for the selected tableviewcell and pass the associated string but keep getting "unrecognized selector.."
When using DLog the console displays the correct string. On the view im passing info. to I have an NSString setup.  Thanks for any help you can provide!

Here is the prepareforsegue code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"kShowMovie"])
    {
        MoviePlayerNEWViewController *dvc = (MoviePlayerNEWViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DemoVideos *demovideo = [_tableContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        dvc.videoDemoString = demovideo.vd_link;


        DLog(@"Video link to pass = %@",demovideo.vd_link);
    }

    UIViewController * controller = segue.destinationViewController;
    [controller setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
}
```

Comment: Please show the complete error message.

Comment: Martin, here is the rest of the error message:       2013-12-24 18[22715:1803] TestFlight: Crash Handlers are installed
2013-[22715:70b] persistentStoreCoordinator
2013-app[22715:17411] TestFlight: Started Session
2013- app[22715:17411] TestFlight: App Token is recognized
2013-12-24 18:28:20.701 app[22715:70b] NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore error: com.app.app has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement
2013-12-24 18:28:22.413 app[22715:70b] -[UINavigationController setVideoDemoString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcee5f40
(lldb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is saying that the controller you're trying to call setVideoDemoString: on is a UINavigationController, not a MoviePlayerNEWViewController as you think it is. You probably want this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"kShowMovie"])
    {
        UINavigationController *nav = segue.destinationViewController;
        MoviePlayerNEWViewController *dvc = nav.topViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DemoVideos *demovideo = [_tableContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        dvc.videoDemoString = demovideo.vd_link;


        DLog(@"Video link to pass = %@",demovideo.vd_link);
    }

    UIViewController * controller = segue.destinationViewController;
    [controller setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
}
```